# xtk mesh loading errors

Tags: xtk

I'm trying to load several freesurfer files (.pial, .inflated) and the javascript console is recording these errors:

```
 Uncaught RangeError: ArrayBuffer length minus the byteOffset is not a multiple of the element size.
```

Other things load fine, such as dicom, nifti, .smoothwm, some .pial, etc. I'm using Chrome 25.0.1364.97

Comment: Can you share a mesh which doesn't work?

Comment: Sure @haehn, can I email a sample mesh to you?

Comment: Is there an email address I can send the sample mesh to?

Comment: oh yea sorry dev at goxtk.com